# Change orientation whithout accelerometer

Tags: screen, accessibility, orientation

I didn't notice when I brough this phone the lack of accelerometer. And now is an ordeal to read/see certain apps and webpages. Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for a solution that works ootb for 2.2 through if there is a way that requires to upgrade I accept that too.t

Answer (score 0):

To easily toggle the portrait/landscape mode you can install the app [**Power Toggles**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dpower+toggles+android&pcampaignid=APPU_et6uU6LOMobb7Aacm4HACA) from the Play Store. Then add a notification toggle with the Rotation Control. Once enabled when you click on the rotation control icon it allows you to choose between the two view modes (port/land).

Being in the notification bar means you can almost always access it. I find it really useful!